# In Active Directory, how do I determine type of ActiveDirectoryAccessRule?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I can get a collection of access rules for an Active Directory object using code such as

```
ActiveDirectorySecurity ads = directoryEntry.ObjectSecurity;
AuthorizationRuleCollection arc = ads.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule adar in arc)
{
    // get rule properties
}
```

However, I would like to know if each rule is also of one of the ActiveDirectoryAccessRule subtypes such as PropertyAccessRule.

Is this possible? I don't see a class property that provides this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `is` to check for the type - for example:

```
if (adar is System.DirectoryServices.PropertyAccessRule )
{
// do whatever you need to do if it is a PropertyAccessRule...
}
```

you can do this with the following because all inherit from `ActiveDirectoryAccessRule` :

```
System.DirectoryServices.CreateChildAccessRule
System.DirectoryServices.DeleteChildAccessRule
System.DirectoryServices.DeleteTreeAccessRule
System.DirectoryServices.ExtendedRightAccessRule
System.DirectoryServices.ListChildrenAccessRule
System.DirectoryServices.PropertyAccessRule
System.DirectoryServices.PropertySetAccessRule
```

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule.aspx#inheritanceContinued

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I didn't get any positive hits, which means either I misunderstand the class structure or something else.

Comment: So in your loop see waht adar.GetType() is. It's possible your ACL doesn't have what you're expecting to be in it.